Created a Scala (Native-compatible) program that scores words in Scrabble. Any refactor tips?
As said in the title, I used Scala to make a simple little program that takes a formatted input string representing a word in Scrabble and spits out its score, including a message explaining where the points are coming from. I'm a fan of how it's turned out and haven't run into any bugs, but I'm curious if anyone has tips on how to condense it further or make the code more readable or editable (if needed). Basically just sanity checking myself that I did this well and didn't overlook any major programming do's/do-not's.
/** Scorble - a simple Scrabble word score calculator.
 *
 */

import scala.io.StdIn.readLine;

object Scorble {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Check that input has been given, and convert it to lowercase if so.
    var word: String = "";
    try {
      word = args(0).toLowerCase();
    } catch {
      // If no argument has been passed, start interactive loop.
      case e: IndexOutOfBoundsException => {
        print(usage);
        word = readLine();
        while (word != null && word != "") {
          word = word.toLowerCase();
          main(Array(word));
          print("\n> ");
          word = readLine();
        }
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }

    // Things we need to track:
    var wordMult: Int = 1; // Double/Triple word score tracker
    var scoreString: String = ""; // Stores visual output of numbers sum
    var scores: Array[Int] = Array(); // An array that will hold dictionary
                                      // value of each tile, as well as
                                      // negatives for multipliers (explained above)

    // If characters aren't letters or special symbols, show error msg.
    try {
      scores = word.map(letterValues(_)).toArray[Int];
    } catch {
      case e: NoSuchElementException => {
        Console.err.println("Please insert a valid word. Type `scorble` for usage.");
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }

    // Check for word scores
    while (scores(0) < 0) {
      wordMult *= -scores(0); // Factor in word multiplier for later math.
      scores = scores.tail; // Trim first character
      word = word.tail;
    }

    // First pass fixes multipliers and prepares output string.
    for (x <- 0 to (scores.length - 1)) {

      if (scores(x) >= 0) {
        if (x > 0) scoreString += " + "; // Don't add plus sign to beginning.
        scoreString += s"[${word(x).toUpper}] ${scores(x)}";
      } else {
        scores(x - 1) = -scores(x) * scores(x - 1); // Multiply value
        scoreString += s"(x${-(scores(x))}=${scores(x - 1)})"
        scores(x) = 0; // Then remove multiplier from play.
      }

    }

    println(scoreString + s" = ${scores.sum[Int]}")
    if (wordMult > 1) {
      println(s"[${wordMult}x Word!] ${scores.sum[Int]} x $wordMult = ${scores.sum[Int] * wordMult}")
    }
  }
}

def usage = """SCORBLE - Scrabble word score calculator
              |
              |- Use '_' for blank tile.
              |- Use '2' or '3' after a letter for double/triple letter scores respectively.
              |  - Ex: "driv3ers" if 'v' is on triple letter
              |- Use them at the beginning of a word to signify a double/triple word score.
              |  - Ex: "3fork2s" if triple word with 'k' on double letter.
              |
              |Use Ctrl-D or press Enter without input to quit.
              |> """.stripMargin;

val letterValues: Map[Char, Int] = Map(
  'a' -> 1,
  'b' -> 3,
  'c' -> 3,
  'd' -> 2,
  'e' -> 1,
  'f' -> 4,
  'g' -> 2,
  'h' -> 4,
  'i' -> 1,
  'j' -> 8,
  'k' -> 5,
  'l' -> 1,
  'm' -> 3,
  'n' -> 1,
  'o' -> 1,
  'p' -> 3,
  'q' -> 10,
  'r' -> 1,
  's' -> 1,
  't' -> 1,
  'u' -> 1,
  'v' -> 4,
  'w' -> 4,
  'x' -> 8,
  'y' -> 4,
  'z' -> 10,
  '_' -> 0,
  '2' -> -2,
  '3' -> -3
)


Decomposition
Don't dump all logic into the main() function. That's not the proper way to design an application.
Instead, decompose the problem into subproblems and introduce narrow-focused application components representing these subproblems.
And you don't need inline comments (remember: inline comment is a code-smell), when each responsibility in your code is given a name that communicates its intent and can be properly documented.
Don't conflate doc comments and inline comments. There are guidelines on how to write Scaladoc, documentation is the proper tool for describing the behavior of a code element, covering all edge-cases, providing usage examples and whatnot.
Exceptions vs Basic parameter validation
Catching an IndexOutOfBounds exception instead of checking if array is not empty isn't a case when you need to use try/catch.
Similarly, processing the user input and then throwing a NoSuchElementException only makes your code more difficult to follow. It would be cleaner to validate the input string instead.
Embrace Declarative programming style
It's advisable to avoid writing imperative code in Scala (e.g.: your while loop with mutable state is a classic example of imperative coding style).
Prefer tail-recursive functions and for-comprehensions over imperative code constructs. Otherwise, you're basically doing Java without semicolons (wait, you do have semicolons... they are unnecessary in Scala).

This is exactly the kind of input I was looking for! I appreciate it a lot :)
